# Pop items in list and create dataframe from results

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to pop from a list, compare the value popped to a random dice a few times and return a dataframe  showing the value of the popped value up until the point the value stops being greater than the random dice.

This is the code I have so far:

```
size = 10
csv_file = [0.2,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7]
for i in range(size):
    obs = csv_file.pop()
    func = lambda x: x if x > random.uniform(0,1) else False
    states = dict(state_leads=func(obs))
    states['lead_opps'] = func(states['state_leads'])
    states['opp_comp'] = func(states['lead_opps'])
states_df = pd.DataFrame([states],columns=states.keys())
```

Comment: You're redeclaring `states` each time through the loop, wiping out the previous contents.

Comment: also what should happen when ```False > random.uniform(0, 1)``` ?

Comment: @quester then that returns False, False is 0 right or am I mistaken

Comment: it should return 0...

Comment: @quester no...False > random.uniform(0,1) would return False because False = 0